# Definir el valor del contador

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente función que definí para saber cuantas veces aparece el carácter "3" dentro de un string, pero también quiero que si este aparece 0 veces, tiene que devolver "@" en lugar de "0". Intente definir que si `cant == 0` entonces cant="@". Pero me sigue retornando "0". Me pueden ayudar? les dejo el código acá abajo.

```
 `def cantAparicionesTres (histClin):
 cantidad=0
 for pos in range (len(histClin)):
   if histClin[pos]=="3":
        cantidad+=1
   if cantidad==0:
    cantidad=="@"
   return cantidad`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de *asignar* una `@`, estás comparando contra `@`

```
 if cantidad == 0:
    cantidad == "@"
```

La forma correcta es:

```
 if cantidad == 0:
    cantidad = "@"
```

Comment: Tenes razón, errores por apurado. Muchas gracias!